# Копирование элементов контейнера

Tags: массивы, vector, структуры, c++, итераторы

Ребята, такой вопрос: как скопировать элемент одного контейнера в другой?

```
struct person
    {
        char *name;
        char *secondname;

    };
    vector <person> first, second;
```

нужно скопировать определенное количество элементов из first в second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если заменить `char*` на `std::string`, то задача стает очень простой. Более того, я даже рекомендую так делать. Тогда копирование будет выглядеть так

```
second.push_back(first[2]);
```

Но в Вашем случае нужно сделать немножко сложнее

```
person tmp = first[2];
tmp.name = strdup(tmp.name);
tmp.secondname = strdup(tmp.secondname);
second.push_back(tmp);
```

две строки в центре делают копию строк. Если этого не сделать, то структуры в одном и другом векторе будут указывать на одну и ту же память. И если одну из них почистить хорошо, то другая будет указывать в пустоту. Отслеживать память достаточно сложно.

str::string умеет делать подсчет ссылок, так что память лишнюю тратить не будет (хотя есть разные реализации).

Comment: отлично спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

как я понимаю, то куда указывают **`*name`** и **`*secondname`** тоже надо скопировать...

тогда вам надо реализовать для своей структуры

1. конструктор по умолчанию
2. конструктор копирования
3. оператор присваивания
4. деструктор

тогда сможете работать как с обычными типами int,float...

главное всё правильно реализовать (реализация ни чем не отличается от такой же реализации для class'а), так же незабываем про выделение\освобождение памяти.

ну и соответственно описание вектора [en](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), [ru](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: спасибо за документацию